# how to link file upload button to flip card

Tags: html, css

I am currently in index.html and I have added flip card as a profile photo for my code I have also included a a file uploader button but I dont know how to link the file uploader button code to the flip card so that once you have selected an image it would automatically display onto the Flip card I have also added CSS to the flip card but there is no CSS to file uploader button

Website for the flip card I have used: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_flip_card

Website I have used for the file uploader button: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_html_file_upload_button.

```
   //index.html
```

<--flip card-->
```

```
               <head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
 body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.flip-card {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-card-front, .flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-card-front {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: black;
}

.flip-card-back {
  background-color: #2980b9;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Card Flip with Text</h1>
<h3>Hover over the image below:</h3>
<div class="flip-card">
  <div class="flip-card-inner">
     <div class="flip-card-front">
        <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:300px;height:300px;">
      </div>
      <div class="flip-card-back">                                 
      </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

                <!--Flip card-->
                                
                                <!-- File uploader button-->
<html>
<body>

<form action="action_page.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Select image to upload:
  <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
  <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>

<--flip card-->
                          

      
                                <!-- File uploader button index.html -->


                    <html>
<body>

<form action="action_page.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Select image to upload:
  <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
  <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
                                <!-- index.html File uploader button-->
```

//PHP for file uploader button separate file action_page.php

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
  $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
  if($check !== false) {
    echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
    $uploadOk = 1;
  } else {
    echo "File is not an image.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
  }
}

// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
  echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
  echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
  echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
  echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
  } else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code for the image the homepage works but I can see that you are trying to implement the flipcard functionality on the file upload button, as per the css properties even if you add the flipcard on the button it wouldn't work as expected, because the flipcard will show an image type on hover and flip the button and you won't be able to upload the file.

**Try this**

````html
```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
 body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.flip-card {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-card-front, .flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-card-front {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: black;
}

.flip-card-back {
  background-color: #2980b9;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Card Flip with Text</h1>
<h3>Hover over the image below:</h3>
<div class="flip-card">
  <div class="flip-card-inner">
     <div class="flip-card-front">
        <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:300px;height:300px;">
      </div>
      <div class="flip-card-back">                                 </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

                <!--Flip card-->
                                
                                <!-- File uploader button-->
<p>Click on the "Choose File" button to upload a file:</p>
<form action="/action_page.php">
<input type="file" id="myFile" name="filename">
<input type="submit">
</form>
````

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219230/discussion-on-answer-by-bijin-abraham-how-to-link-file-upload-button-to-flip-car).